# Does the word レストラン make saying 中国レストラン strange?

Tags: word-choice

I see that the WWWJDIC emphasizes western style restaurants for the word レストラン. So would there be a better word to use in 中国レストラン?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. `中国レストラン` sounds a bit awkward. A normal way to say it is `中華料理店` or `中華料理屋`. You don't use `中国` for Chinese foods but rather `中華`.

Comment: That does look pretty familiar.